# ¿Cómo Mantener una imagen a la izquierda y otra al centro en un header?

Tags: html, css

Quiero mantener una imagen en mi header a la izquierda y otra centrada, el problema es que no consigo hacerlo, este es el código que he utilizado:

```
<img src= "../resources/menu.png" id="button-menu" width= "40px" height= "30px"/><img src= "../resources/logo.png" id="logo-menu" width="200" height="57"/ >


header{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: auto;
    background: #34495E;
}



header #button-menu{
    margin-top: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;

    
}
header #logo-menu{
    margin-top: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline;
    

}
```

Pero este es el resultado que recibo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te hago los siguientes comentarios:

- Para estos casos en los que noto que tratas de poner 3 elementos en una *especie* de *rejilla* considero que te funcionará mejor aplicar el módulo `CSS Grid`
- Dentro del `header` se puede componer una estructura mas o menos así:

  - El `header` como etiqueta padre o contenedora
  - Dentro irá un `section` que contendrá las 3 imágenes
- Dentro del contenedor generamos 3 columnas de igual medida y damos una disposición de tipo `grid`
- Al contenedor de las 3 imágenes le damos un `padding` de 10px para separar a los elementos del borde de su etiqueta padre

Propuesta

```html
    <style>
      .encabezado-imagenes {
        border: 1px solid red;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        padding: 10px;
      }
      .encabezado-imagenes__imagen {
        border: 1px solid teal;
        width: 90%;
      }
    </style>
    <header class="encabezado">
      <section class="encabezado-imagenes">
        <img src="" alt="" class="encabezado-imagenes__imagen">
        <img src="" alt="" class="encabezado-imagenes__imagen">
      </section>
    </header>
```

Nota: Agrega a este código rutas a imágenes para que puedas notar el efecto esperado, ahorita no verías mas que una línea por que no tengo vinculado ningún recurso gráfico.

**Lecturas altamente recomendadas**

- [repeat sintax](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#repeat-notation)
- [módulo CSS Grid](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#overview)
- [Definiendo el grid](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#track-sizing)

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, tu código divide mi header en 3 y cuadra las imagenes en esas 3 columnas pero estiradas, yo lo que necesito es una imagen a la izquierda del todo en su tamaño original y otra en el centro a su tamaño original, pero alineadas verticalmente. Salida de tu código: https://i.imgur.com/aTJdFqG.png

Comment: quita el ancho que yo declare

Comment: funciona gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Y si intentas poner el botón en absolute

```
header #button-menu{
    margin-top: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
}
```

y aqui dale mas espacio al margin left

```
header #logo-menu{
    margin-top: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 50px ;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline;
    

}
```

Espero haberte ayudado uwu

Comment: En ese caso salen superpuestas a la izquierda del todo las dos imagenes: https://i.imgur.com/ECSazHZm.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Prueba poniendo un display:flex a tu header, solo que debes de agregarle un alto, por ejemplo: height: 70px, luego pones un: justify-content: space-evenly y por último agregas un: align-items:center

PD: Quítale los estilos a los elementos dentro de tu header.

Comment: añadiendo el display: flex; y estableciendo la altura se soluciono, gracias